# ASP.NET Core does not log me in

Tags: asp.net-core

EDIT: So After many failed attempts to figure out why this is not working I decided to create a project and choose to have user login implemented from there so it will configure everything for me.
after that I just scraped the automated login/register code and replaced it with my own. everything works amazingly well. I am pretty sure in my original version I missed some needed parameter

I am trying to make a simple login function. but I cant seem to get it to work and it drives me crazy ..

so I do my   shared folder under _layout.cshtml I have added this

```
 @inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager;
 and then just a little later inside my navbar I added this elements 

  <ul class="navbar-nav  ml-auto">
                        @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User)) {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <form method="post" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Logout">
                                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link py-0" style="width:auto">
                                    Logout @User.Identity.Name
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </li>
                        }
                        else {
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Register">Register</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Login">Login</a>
                        </li>
                        }
                    </ul>
```

and in my controller I added this I called this controller UserController.cs
If I enter wrong login info . like wrong password or username it will tell me I that. so the connection with the database is no issue. but when I am send in my "Home" Index I am not logged it. as if it does not create a session I am not sure

```
   [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(Login model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         
        var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName,model.Password,
            model.RememberMe,false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //creates a temponary sign in session cookie. that cookie is going to be lost after the browser is closed
       
            return RedirectToAction("index", "home");
        }
        //if succeeded = false then ew llop through the error list

        
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,"Invalid Login");
      
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: At `//creates a temponary sign in session cookie. that cookie is going to be lost after the browser is closed`, did you remove code, or isn't there any, or does that belong above `signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`? Do you have cookie auth configured [as explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1), so `services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie();`?

Comment: I removed it. I used the structure for register to automatically log in after register.
but that also does not work. it creates the user. but it does not loggin after. 
Here is that removed line. bur note that this line is for sign up onbject 
       await signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

Comment: I've also updated my comment, do you configure cookie auth? And does the response in the developer tools of your browser show a set-cookie header? And to be clear, the code exactly as shown, shows the behavior you describe?

Comment: I did not. I added it. but still I cant log in

Comment: cant edit my previews comment. I can see from dev tools in chrome that a session is created .AspNetCore.Identity.Application ... I wonder if its in my cshtml code the problem and not in the controller

Comment: This might be down to `UseAuthentication` not being in the correct place inside of `Configure`, which is a common mistake in this area.

Comment: Hello @KirkLarkin how do I check that? I think I should note that I did not choose to have register/login created on the start of my project. maybe that is why I am having this issue ? I wanted to add everything on my own so I can understand how it works. as it turns out terrible idea so far.

Comment: Check the `Configure` method in the `Startup` class. It should have a call to `UseAuthentication` between `UseRouting` and `UseEndpoints` or before `UseMvc`, depending on whether it's ASP.NET Core 3.x or 2.x.

Comment: Hello , I have added it but still cant login      app.UseRouting();
      
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();

Comment: `UseAuthentication` also needs to be above `UseAuthorization`. Do you see a cookie in the browser's developer tools that's named something like `AspNetCore.Identity.Application`?

Comment: Yes I do see a cookie I have cleared it out and move UseAuthetication above Use Arturization still nothing. I am really baffled onto why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the whole working demo like below:

View(Login.cshtml):

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@model LoginViewModel
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"].</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section>
            <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Email" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Password" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label asp-for="RememberMe">
                                <input asp-for="RememberMe" />
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="Register" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">Register as a new user?</a>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <a asp-action="ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                </p>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            @{
                var schemes = await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync();
                var loginProviders = schemes.ToList();
                if (loginProviders.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                            for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.Name account">@provider.Name</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{ await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial"); }
}
```

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;

    public AccountController(
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
    }
   
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }           
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
            }
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }      
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddSignInManager()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            o.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            o.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        })
        .AddIdentityCookies(o => { });
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Hello, was doing exactly that and it was not working. but after i created a new project with user auth (as the one you are showing) and replaced everything with my code it worked.

I have accepted your answer as the correct one since it actually works and for the efford you put it making it. thanks a lot for your time @Rena